# VisualStudio is picking up incorrect assembly version when using project-internal referencing

Tags: visual-studio-2013, .net-assembly

I have a project which interfaces to external hardware using an API supplied by the manufacturer. Recently a new version of the hardware came out with a slightly modified API. I need to be able to connect to both versions.

I copied the 2 versions of the API into 2 folders in the project:

```
Libs
  +--APIv2
  +--APIv4
```

and added project references to the DLLs in APIv4. My intention is to access the v2 API dynamically using reflection.

The strange thing is that, although I add the v4 API from the APIv4 folder as references, it is always the v2 API which is actually referenced. The Path attribute of the reference is the path to the v2 API - /Libs/APIv2.

However, if both versions are stored outside of the project and the v4 API is referenced then this does not happen. ie if I reference v4, then v4 is actually referenced.

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that I can set an attribute on each reference: `Specific Version` = true. This seems to resolve my problem.